# Getting the name of a tag

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I've noticed that in using the default Drupal 8 API to get a feed of articles (using the REST View) the Tags field is returned as the following:

```
"field_tags" : [{
  "target_id" : "1", 
   "target_type" : "taxonomy_term",
   "target_uuid" : "4d2cac04-a0a6-4c0a-8c13-34ba44a474f0",
   "url" : "\/site\/taxonomy\/term\/1"
}]
```

This returns an entity reference, but you never get the actual name of the tag. In the above instance, the name of that tag is actually *Lorem*. I can't seem to find a way of adding a property into the `field_tags` object to include the actual name of the tag. Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think there's anything for getting the fields of a referenced entity through the parent entity, you might just have to make another GET to the taxonomy term resource with the entity ID you have

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, storing the taxonomy term data separately and then querying that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Clive said is the right answer as far as core goes. You have to make another request.

There are some contrib projects that provide more flexible interfaces. One of them is https://www.drupal.org/project/graphql, which allows you to execute a query and specify what data you want to have shown. I believe it's still fairly experimental though.